# controls not shown on forms in c#.net 2005

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

hello
     i have created a form in c#.NET 2005 & add controls on it but now controls are not visible still the code for each control is present & all controls visible property is set to true Can someone please tell me how to show the controls on form again.... its urgent

Comment: How do you add your controls ? Through designer or programmatically ? Have you tried to debug your form building it step-by-step ?

Comment: Is the constructor calling InitializeComponents() ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the resource file properly mapped to the file, if its not included properly the controls might not be visible

Answer (score 0):

Look in the form.Designer class.

There should be a form.cs, form.resx and form.designer class when you create a new form in VS 2005.